# How to convert NAD83 coordinates to Cartesian coordinates expressed in meters?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, nad83, cartesian

I have coordinates (longitude, latitude) expressed in NAD83 and I would like to be able to convert them to Cartesian coordinates (X [m], Y [m]) in order to use them for modeling. A similar topic deals with this but the answer provided does not really match my request. What I want, in a practical way, is to go from: (-79; 48) to something like (1500m, 200m).

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of projections with units of meters. Your task is to choose a standard projected coordinate system one that's appropriate to your data extent. To do so you really need to first choose the GIS software you will use for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Vince. I don't have a lot of geographic points (5 to 7) so I want to do the conversion manually. Knowing systems whose units are in meters, I can manage for the rest. Do you know of any systems whose coordinates are expressed in meters, please? Is the Lambert-93 is?

Comment: There's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Locating_a_position_using_UTM_coordinates (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_reference_system for a more general discussion)

Comment: For a few coordinates you can do it online: http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4269&t_srs=5320